# Keep checkbox checked or unchecked based on some value

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am using checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{areaFilter.area_name | lowercase}}" ng-checked="true" />
```

I want to keep checkbox already checked or unchecked while page loading depend on some value (selectedArea) :
Like

```
if(selectedArea.indexOf(areaFilter.area_name) > -1)
```

Then

```
ng-clicked="true"
```

else

```
ng-clicked="false"
```

How can I do this in HTML page.

Please guide.

Comment: please create fiddle or plunker.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.10"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.checked = true;
      $scope.unchecke = function(checked){
        if(checked){
           $scope.checked = false;
        }else{
          $scope.checked = true;
        }
      };
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked | lowercase" ng-click="unchecke(checked)" id="ids" name="ids">
</body>
</html>
```